# Unregistering single IntentFilter from BroadcastReceiver in android

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I'm registering many `IntentFilter` to a single `BroadcastReceiver`and unregistering all the `IntentFilter` when these are not required as in the code below.

Thing are working well at this point. But now I need to unregister a single `IntentFilter` instead of all.

How this can be achieved or any workaround or better approach?

```
private void registerBroadcastReceiver() {
        Log.i(TAG, LogHelper.at() + "Begin");

        LocalBroadcastManager
                .getInstance(getActivity())
                .registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,
                        new IntentFilter(getString(R.string.onInitiateCustomerVerificationSUCCESS)));

        LocalBroadcastManager
                .getInstance(getActivity())
                .registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,
                        new IntentFilter(getString(R.string.onInitiateCustomerVerificationFAILURE)));

        Log.i(TAG, LogHelper.at() + "End");
    }

    private void unRegisterBroadcastReceiver() {
        Log.i(TAG, LogHelper.at() + "Begin");

        LocalBroadcastManager
                .getInstance(OkeKeyApplication.getAppContext())
                .unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);

        Log.i(TAG, LogHelper.at() + "End");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the IntentFilter by adding actions. Then you can register the receiver only once.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(getString(R.string.onInitiateCustomerVerificationSUCCESS));
filter.addAction(getString(R.string.onInitiateCustomerVerificationFAILURE));
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity())
    .registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
```

To change the IntentFilter, I would just unregister it, and register it again with a new IntentFilter.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method  but you can  follow one of the following ways -

1. Register a different receiver for that particular IntentFilter and unregister it whenever you want . There will be no effect on other registered receivers.
2. Unregister the receiver and then at the same time register the same receiver again but only for the  rest of the IntentFilters.